# Word list in a RecyclerView and the favourite section of my app doesn't work properly

Tags: java, android, database, android-recyclerview

I developed a vocabulary app where users can select their favorite words to a favourite section. I have two problems.

First, my code looks okay but when I choose a word from the list it doesn't show in the favorite section immediately. However, when I re-open the application it appears there.

The second problem is with the words which repeat in list with any run.

Here's my code :

Adapter list

```
package farmani.com.essentialwordsforielts.mainPage;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import farmani.com.essentialwordsforielts.R;
import farmani.com.essentialwordsforielts.innerpage.ActivityInnerPage;

public class AdapterList extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {

Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
TextView title;
ImageView avatar;
LinearLayout cardAdapter;

public AdapterList(Context context){
    this.context = context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}


@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_card_view, parent, false);

    title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title1);
    avatar = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
    cardAdapter = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.card_adapter);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.title.setText(MainActivity.list.get(position).getWord());
    String img = MainActivity.list.get(position).getImg();
    int id = MainActivity.context.getResources().getIdentifier(img, "drawable", MainActivity.context.getPackageName());
    holder.avatar.setImageResource(id);
    holder.cardAdapter.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

    holder.cardAdapter.setId(position);

}

View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int position = view.getId();
        Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.context, ActivityInnerPage.class);
        intent.putExtra("name", "list");
        intent.putExtra("id", position + "");
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        MainActivity.context.startActivity(intent);

    }
};

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return MainActivity.list.size();
}
}
```

Adapter favorite

```
package farmani.com.essentialwordsforielts.mainPage;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import farmani.com.essentialwordsforielts.R;
import farmani.com.essentialwordsforielts.innerpage.ActivityInnerPage;

public class AdapterFav extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {

Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
TextView title;
ImageView avatar;
LinearLayout cardAdapter;

public AdapterFav(Context context){
    this.context = context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}


@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_card_view, parent, false);

    title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title1);
    avatar = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
    cardAdapter = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.card_adapter);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.title.setText(MainActivity.favorite.get(position).getWord());
    String img = MainActivity.favorite.get(position).getImg();
    int id = MainActivity.context.getResources().getIdentifier(img, "drawable", MainActivity.context.getPackageName());
    holder.avatar.setImageResource(id);
    holder.cardAdapter.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
    holder.cardAdapter.setId(position);

}

View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int position = view.getId();
        Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.context, ActivityInnerPage.class);
        intent.putExtra("name", "favorite");
        intent.putExtra("id", position + "");
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        MainActivity.context.startActivity(intent);

    }
};

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return MainActivity.favorite.size();
}
}
```

Comment: The code you have shared, has nothing to do with your problems. Please share the adapter that you have used to populate your `RecyclerView` where you are showing the list of your words.

Comment: I'll edit my post with codes u need . tnx

Comment: I edited my post with new codes . please let me know

Answer (score 0):

When you update  your data set call adapater.notifyChange();

Comment: Your code that adds the item to the favorites list. After you add the item to the favorites list. call the adapters notifyChange methed.

Comment: my adapter is in my page fragment .java and favorite code is in main activity and inner activity. how I can have access ? I even made adapterFav public .

Comment: inner activity:

 private void updateFavorited(){
        database.execSQL( "UPDATE main SET fav = 1 WHERE id = " + id);

    }

    private void updateUnfavorited(){
        database.execSQL( "UPDATE main SET fav = 0 WHERE id = " + id);

    }